# Operators from $\ell^\infty$ into $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have the following question related to $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}).$ How can I construct a bounded, linear operator from $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ into $c_0(\mathbb{N})$ which is non-compact?

It is clear that $\ell^\infty$ is a Grothendieck space with Dunford-Pettis property, hence any operator from $\ell^\infty$ into a separable Banach space must be strictly singular. But I do not know any example above which is non-compact.

Comment: From  problem VII.3 in Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*: The bounded linear operators from $\ell_\infty$ to $c_0$ correspond to the weak$^*$ null sequences in $\ell_\infty^*$ and a bounded operator $T$ from $\ell_\infty$ to $c_0$ is compact iff the sequence $(T^*e_i^*)$ is norm null in $\ell_\infty^*$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bounded operator $T:\ell_\infty\rightarrow c_0$ has the form $Tx=(x_n^*(x))$ for some weak$^*$ null sequence $(x_n^*)$ in $\ell_\infty^*$.  A set $K\subset c_0$ is relatively compact if and only if there is a $x\in c_0$ such that $|k_n|\le |x_n|$ for all $k\in K$ and all $n\ge1$.  From these two facts, it follows that $T(B({\ell_\infty}))$ is relatively compact if and only if the representing sequence $(x_n^*)$ is norm-null.

So, you need only find a sequence in $\ell_\infty^*$ that is weak$^*$ null, but not norm null. 
Such a sequence exists in $\ell_\infty^*$ since: 1) weak$^*$ convergent sequences in $\ell_\infty^*$ are weakly convergent ($\ell_\infty^*$ has the Grothendieck property), and  2) $\ell_\infty^*$ does not have the Schur property (weakly convergent sequences are norm convergent).

(There may be a less roundabout way of showing the the result of the preceding paragraph.)

Comment: What is a null sequence?

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry, a sequence that converges to the zero vector.

Comment: I expected a direct example but now I understand why this is not immediate. Thank  you!